# How to make this if statement work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've made a simplified example (see demo) of the code I'm struggling with. I first have a function that calculates the number of lines  the `<p>` has inside of the wrapper div. Depending on the number (1, 2 or 3 lines), the wrapper div should get an extra class name.

These are the errors I can't work out:

- The function stops (as you can see in the logging) after it has run:

  ```
  if (getRows('.item p') === 1) {
  }
  ```
- When I log the result in that function I get the Window object where I would need the specific div to add the class so that my absolute link can be positioned correctly

So the result would be that the absolute link should be position accordingly to the number of lines.

Yes, I know this code can be written differently (as in just placing the absolute link under my p..) but it is the CMS who renders it like this and this would be the easiest workaround.. If you want to view the results of how it should be you can add item_1 on the first item div, item_2 on second and so on.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pndJx/

```
if (getRows('.item p') === 1) {
console.log('1 line');
console.log(this);
}

if (getRows('.item p') === 2) {
console.log('2 lines');
}

if (getRows('.item p') === 3) {
console.log('3 lines');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an each statement: http://jsfiddle.net/astynax777/pndJx/1/

```
$('.item p').each(function() {
    var rows = getRows(this);
    switch (rows)
    {
        case 1:
            console.log('1 line');
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('2 lines');
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('3 lines');
            break;
    };
});

function getRows(selector) {
    var height = $(selector).height();
    var font_size = $(selector).css('font-size');
    var scale = 1.50
    var line_height = Math.floor(parseInt(font_size) * scale);
    var rows = height / line_height;
    return Math.round(rows);
}
```

Comment: Nice, just what I needed, can add the relevant classes for each case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

write your code in this way

```
$('.item p').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this),
       rows  = getRows($this);

   console.log('%d lines', rows);

   /* add class */
   $this.parent().addClass('item_' + rows);

});
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSevE/

Comment: Hi Fabirizio, thanks for the tip, could have been written better indeed but wanted a quick example to show.

Comment: @Yunowork you can even simplify the logic to add your classname to the parent div... se my update

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to run that logic for each `<div>` individually. If that is the case, then I'd suggest this:

```
function getRows(selector, context) {
    var height = $(selector, context).height();
    var font_size = $(selector, context).css('font-size');
    var scale = 1.50
    var line_height = Math.floor(parseInt(font_size) * scale);
    var rows = height / line_height;
    return Math.round(rows);
}

$('div.item').each(function () {
    if (getRows('.item p', this) === 1) {
        // if ".item p" equals 1 then add class "item_1" to item div
        console.log('1 line');
        console.log(this); //if i log this i get window (the document), but I need to get the specific div to add the class..
    }

    //console gives back result '1 line' since true and does not continue..

    if (getRows('.item p', this) === 2) {
        // if ".item p" equals 2 then add class "item_1" to item div
        console.log('2 lines');
    }

    if (getRows('.item p', this) === 3) {
        // if ".item p" equals 3 then add class "item_1" to item div
        console.log('3 lines');
    }
});
```

Inside the context of the anonymous function passed to `.each()` `this` refers to that specific `<div>` element, rather than the `window`.

Comment: Afaik and tried, I can't add a specific class to the wrapper div of a line?